# Getting value of scanning at Motorola TC55

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode-scanner, android-broadcast, motorola

I want to scan a Barcode in my app. I could start the scan but I do not know how to detect the scanned value. My code looks like

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pick, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // scan
        this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scan).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Start the scanner like in the example:  https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-1874#PROGRAMMING%20INTERFACE                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER");
                intent.putExtra("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.EXTRA_PARAMETER", "TOGGLE_SCANNING");
                view.getContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, receiver, null, 0, null, null);
            }
        });
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // How to detect the scanned value???       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could solve it. This is the code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER");
intent.putExtra("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.api.EXTRA_PARAMETER", "TOGGLE_SCANNING");
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);

getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override        
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                
        String code = intent.getExtras().getString("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.data_string");

        // do something

        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
}
, new IntentFilter("MyIntentAction"));
```

The profile in the `DataWedge` has to enable the output via intent and disable the keystroke output. As intent action is to set a `String` which is the same as `"MyIntentAction"`. Then I get the scanned barcode directly in my Fragment after scanning.

Comment: In order for this to work I also had too add my app as an associated app and I also had to set Intent delivery to Broadcast event.

Comment: Hi, I have a question can you please help me, if I want to use the above code to scan barcode, do I need to import any jar package files or need to install EMDK? or this intent will scan if I'm using the Motorola TC55 device? Please answer.

Comment: @mburm,  I really need your help, I'm with same problem, try the above code, but still not resolving, can you please help me?

Comment: I think there is not necessary any jar package or installation. The `datawedge` has to be configured right that the code above works. I will take a look into my project if there still is included a jar file.

Comment: what is `MyIntentAction` in IntentFilter? Is it datawedge intent action which is `ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER`. because the data is null for me in that receive event.

Comment: `MyIntentAction` is the value of the `Intent action` property in the `Intent output` section of your `DataWedge` profile.

Comment: Either you can create profile programmatically using emdk or you can create profile in datawedge app manually. Check out this link for creating profile programmatically http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-0/tutorial/tutdatacaptureprofile/